# "How to resolve req.body undefined in Node JS "

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express

I am setting up a node js server and in my output of req.body i keep getting undefined, i am trying to requesting SQL data from a form Get request

I am able to retrieve other queries just none involving req.body

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/submit',urlencodedParser,function (req, res){
connection.connect(function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(req.body.lname);
var exist = req.body.lname;
var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname= '" + exist + "'";

connection.query(sql, function(err,result) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(result);
console.log(exist);
console.log(req.body.lname);
console.log("hello");
console.log(result);
});
});
```

'

output:

undefined
[]
undefined
undefined
hello
[]

Comment: Why should a GET request have a body? Use a POST request

Comment: Use a Post request to retrieve table data from SQL. Sorry a bit new to node.js, i was under the understanding that you only use Post to send data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: If you are gonna use GET request, you can use `req.params`.

Answer (score 0):

Get request doesn't carry the `req.body` object.

You will have to use either `req.query` or `req.params` to pass your data or transform your get into post.

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
  connection.connect(function (err) {

    if (err) throw err;
    var exist = req.body.lname;
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname= '" + exist + "'";

    connection.query(sql, function(err,result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else console.log(result);
    });

});
```